# Adobe Lightroom 3 in Wine

Tags: wine, photo-management, adobe

Has anyone got Lightroom 3 working under wine? As with most posts out there, I have successfully completed the install, but where the photos should be (in grid view, loupe view or edit view) there are only gray squares.

I have run `winetricks vcrun6 colorprofile corefonts vista gdiplus` already, no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an answer to your question, but you might also want to have a look at [DarkTable](http://darktable.sourceforge.net/).  It's a native linux application that is still in development, but is already useable, and intended to be a (partial) replacement for Lightroom.

Ubuntu packages for 10.04 ("Lucid") and 10.10 ("Maverick") are available in a [release PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pmjdebruijn/+archive/darktable-release) and an [unstable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pmjdebruijn/+archive/darktable-unstable) (the unstable/development versions might not always work correctly).

Comment: Awesome, looks great. I'll test it a little more comprehensively over the next few weeks and migrate onto it if it doesn't shred any of my photos! :)

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really an answer to your problem, but in my experience Wine, while a lot better than nothing, just isn't going to run something like Lightroom acceptably fast and reliably compared to a supported platform (i.e. Windows or OS X). This is especially true if you're a power user, and use Lightroom as a professional tool.

If you really do rely heavily on Lightroom, and aren't able to find an acceptable native alternative, you might want to consider dual-booting, using Virtualbox to run Windows under Ubuntu, running Lightroom on a separate machine, or just resigning yourself to using Windows or OS X.

Best of luck!

Comment: agreed, +1 for practical answer

Comment: Yep, all completely agreed. After posting that question, I spent the next 30 mins installing it in VBox :) I wasn't expecting it to work (flawlessly | at all), just wanted to give it a shot. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out the entry in the Wine Application Database?:

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20512

See if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks. I have, that's where I got the winetricks idea. Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the beta Wine 1.3 packages from the Wine PPA? http://www.winehq.org/download/deb

There's a comment on AppDB that hinted at success with Wine 1.3.3, and Wine's up to 1.3.4 now.

Comment: I have not, I've been using 1.2, I'll give it a shot, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, just tested with 1.3.4 (latest from PPA) and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

i would avoid ANY ppa that does not say either the name of the app itself or if the name of the app includes words like Stable unless your willing to try to fix any potential issues that may crop up from using an unstable or alpha or beta or testing PPA. let the developers/users who are actually willing to test/try it to try to fix any issues.